# How can i get these different htaccess rules to work properly?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to get this htaccess rules to work:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /?page=$1&show=edit&id=$2 [L]
```

First i thaught this was the solution but it broke my app.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /?page=$1&show=$2&date=$3 [L]
```

Can someone please let me know how to set this up to work?

Comment: Can you provide us with more context, in paticular: "What are you trying to accomplish with these rewrite rules?" and "What errors are you getting?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid rewriting files and directories:

```
RewriteEngine On

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /?page=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /?page=$1&show=edit&id=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /?page=$1&show=$2&date=$3 [L,QSA]
```